# RewriteRule when there is ?id=

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to write a RewriteRule in the .htaccess but I have problems

I try to redirect from:

```
blog/entrada.php?id=2
```

To:

```
/blog/3D-touch
```

This is one of the multiple things I tried and does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/entrada\.php\?id=2$ /blog/3D-touch [L,R=301]
```

What is wrong with my Rule. How to redirect effectively?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querystring is not part of match in RewriteRule directive, to redirect query strings, you need to use RewriteCond one of the following options :

**option 1**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/entrada\.php\?id=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/3D-touch? [NC,L,R]
```

**option 2**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/entrada\.php$ /blog/3D-touch? [NC,L,R]
```

We use an empty question mark **?** at the end of the target url to discard the old query strings, otherwise these query strings get appened to the target url by default.

Change the **R** to **R=301** if you want to make the redirection permanent.

Comment: The two options work very well. In option 1 RewriteRule why do you write ^ can you explain that, please?

Answer (score 0):

use from this code

```
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog/entrada.php?id=$1
```

this code will redirect all urls which have blog/ to blog/entrada.php and put after value of blog/ to $_GET['id']

you should have following code n the top location of your htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. I do not want to redirect all the url which have blog/ to blog/entrada.php. I say in the question I need to direct from blog\/entrada\.php\?id=2  to /blog/3D-touch or what is the same 3D-touch.php (as I have another rule to get rid of .php)

Comment: in fact when user entered /blog/3D-touch.php request go to blog\entrada.php?id=2 ?

Comment: blog/entrada.php?id=2 does not exists. This is why I want to redirect